# How to correct my Android program?

Tags: android

What's wrong with the program? When activity A jumps to activity B and requests data from Internet to update the Android UI, the UI can't update. Then adt shows an error:

> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Here's the code:

```
public class MyStatusesActivity extends Activity {
  Button re;
  TextView mystatuses;
  StatusesAPI sa;
  ProgressDialog progressDialog;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_statuses);
    initView();
    action();
    userTimeline();
  }
  private void action() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    re.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      MyStatusesActivity.this.finish();
    }
  });
}
private void initView() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this,null, "加载中...",true, true);
  mystatuses = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mystatuses);
  re = (Button) findViewById(R.id.re);
}
public void userTimeline() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  sa = new StatusesAPI(SplashActivity.accessToken);
  sa.userTimeline(SharePre.readUID(this), 0, 0, 20, 1, false, FEATURE.ALL, false, listener);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_statuses, menu);
  return true;
}
RequestListener listener = new RequestListener(){
  @Override
  public void onComplete(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("sina", arg0);
    try {
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(arg0);
      JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("statuses");
      JSONObject jsonOb = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
      mystatuses.setText(jsonOb.getString("text"));
      progressDialog.dismiss();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(WeiboException arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("sina", "WeiboException:"+arg0.getMessage());
  }

  @Override
  public void onIOException(IOException arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i("sina", "IOException:"+arg0.getMessage());
  }
};
```

Comment: What did you learn when you searched for this error here or on Google?

Comment: Does `StatusesAPI` perform network-requests on a different thread?

Comment: @LukasKnuth it performs in this activity.i'm the android beginners,i don't konw how to correct it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not dig through your code in detail (please make the effort of abstracting it before posting it to SO), but it seems you are doing something on a different thread (the Request listener maybe is called asynchronous?) and from there you are not allowed to access the UI.

Easy solution: Make a global [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and create it in `onCreate()`, then in the asynchronous method, instead of just executing the code, post it via the handler. This will change Thread context (i.e. allow you to access the UI).